# How to make an asynchronous http call from bot-composer?

Tags: azure, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I'm creating a bot in botcomposer(v1.4.0) which involves an http request. What I'm looking for is an asynchronous call so that I don't have to wait for the response from the http call, while the user can continue to chat with the bot.
Also, I want to prompt the user when the response comes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) would be the best option. Unfortunately, they [are not implemented in Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/6664) at this time. You *might* be able to create a [custom action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions) and accomplish your goal (*my assumption without knowing more of what your requirements are*).